# Multi angle formula of an irrational multiple of theta

Tags: trigonometry

Given that the double angle formula allows you to take $cos(2\theta)$ and put into terms of $cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta)$, would it be possible to do the same to an irrational multiple of \theta such as $cos(\pi\theta)$? By possible, I mean could you do this with a finite number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confined to rational numbers, the answer is no, which can be seen as follows: $ f_{\alpha}(\theta) =  \cos{\alpha\theta} $ has period $2\pi/\alpha$, so $f_{\pi}$ has period $2$. On the other hand, $f_n$ has period ( 2\pi/n ), and hence any arithmetic combination $g(f_{r_1},\dots,f_{r_n})$ of these has $2\pi r$ as a period for some rational $r$. But if a function is continuous and has a rational and an irrational period, the function is constant, as can be seen by considering rational approximations: in this case, you pick a sequence so that the periods become arbitrarily close together (rational approximations to the irrational number, for example), and show that the function's variation along this sequence is arbitrarily small (that's a rough outline; I can dig out a full proof if you want it).

(If you don't restrict to rational numbers, the answer is either "yes, obviously", or "no", depending on what irrational numbers you allow, since obviously you have silly things like $\sin{2\pi x}=2\sin{\pi x}\cos{\pi x}$, or the irrationals are linearly independent over the rationals, and the same proof applies.)

---

However, if you remove the finitary restriction, you can obtain an exact formula over some of the domain of $f_{\alpha}$ using Fourier series: one can show that for integer $n$,
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos{\alpha x} \cos{nx} \, dx = \frac{2\alpha(-1)^n\sin{\pi\alpha}}{\pi(\alpha^2-n^2)}, $$
and then Fourier's theorem gives
$$ \cos{\alpha x} = \frac{\sin{\pi \alpha}}{\pi \alpha}+\frac{2\alpha \sin{\pi\alpha}}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha^2-n^2} \cos{nx} \quad (\lvert x \rvert < \pi), $$
which is perhaps close to what you were after.

(In turn, setting $x=\pi$ in this gives the somewhat esoteric formula
$$ \pi\cot{\pi \alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2-n^2}, $$
which is surprisingly useful.)

Comment: I was trying to get my number into a form that could be transformed from polar to Cartesian